# compare string with equals method and ==

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

I am newbie Java programming and I have a little question about compare string with 
`equals` method and `==`

Example 1: Doesn't work when get input from user but if it has set initial value it works fine.

```
if(str1 == str2) 
 System.out.println("equal");
```

Example 2: always works

```
if(str1.equals(str2))
 System.out.println("equal");
```

if I have to compare string which command can be used.

Comment: Rule of Thumb: If you are not comparing references, always use `.equals()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) points to same location/value, thats why == on string literals works

When you get input from user, it will be treated as new String object.

`equals()` check for values equality whereas `==` check for reference equality.