# Check empty EditText depending on a Spinner

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I have a Spinner which goes from 0 to 10. When we select 5 for example, we get the 5th EditText. I want to check if the 5th EditText is empty after validation button.

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ageEnfants"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Premier enfant"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAgeEnfants1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Deuxième enfant"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAgeEnfants2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Troisième enfant"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAgeEnfants3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Quatrième enfant"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAgeEnfants4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Cinquième enfant"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAgeEnfants5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Sixième enfant"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAgeEnfants6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Septième enfant"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAgeEnfants7"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Huitième enfant"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAgeEnfants8"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Neuvième enfant"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editAgeEnfants10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAgeEnfants9"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#EBEBEB"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Dixième enfant"/>
```

I set the visible gone:

```
editAgeEnfants1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editAgeEnfants2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editAgeEnfants3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editAgeEnfants4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editAgeEnfants5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editAgeEnfants6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editAgeEnfants7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editAgeEnfants8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editAgeEnfants9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editAgeEnfants10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The spinner:

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerEnfantsCharge"
        style="@style/spinner_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enfantsCharge"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:entries="@array/enfantsCharge"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

Strings.xml

```
<string-array name="enfantsCharge">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
</string-array>
```

How I display the EditText:

```
spinnerEnfantsCharge.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 1) {
            ageEnfants.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants2.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants3.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants4.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants5.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants6.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants7.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants8.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants9.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants10.setText("");
        } ... else if (position == 10) {
            ageEnfants.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAgeEnfants10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ageEnfants.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants1.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants2.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants3.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants4.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants5.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants6.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants7.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants8.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants9.setText("");
            editAgeEnfants10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAgeEnfants10.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        ageEnfants.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants1.setText("");
        editAgeEnfants2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants2.setText("");
        editAgeEnfants3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants3.setText("");
        editAgeEnfants4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants4.setText("");
        editAgeEnfants5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants5.setText("");
        editAgeEnfants6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants6.setText("");
        editAgeEnfants7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants7.setText("");
        editAgeEnfants8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants8.setText("");
        editAgeEnfants9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants9.setText("");
        editAgeEnfants10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editAgeEnfants10.setText("");
    }
});
```

On my validation button I did:

```
 else if ((spinnerEnfantsCharge.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1 && editAgeEnfants1.getText().length() == 0) || (spinnerEnfantsCharge.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1 && editAgeEnfants1.getText().length() == 0)) {
                            ageEnfants.requestFocus();
                            ageEnfants.setError("Veuillez entrer l'âge de vos enfants.");
```

But the code will be long if I check all conditions, I want to know if there is a simpler way to check the empty EditText?

### SOLUTION

```
if ((editAgeEnfants1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants1.getText().length() == 0) || (editAgeEnfants2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants2.getText().length() == 0) || (editAgeEnfants3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants3.getText().length() == 0) || (editAgeEnfants4.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants4.getText().length() == 0) || (editAgeEnfants5.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants5.getText().length() == 0) || (editAgeEnfants6.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants6.getText().length() == 0) || (editAgeEnfants7.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants7.getText().length() == 0) || (editAgeEnfants8.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants8.getText().length() == 0) || (editAgeEnfants9.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants9.getText().length() == 0) || (editAgeEnfants10.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && editAgeEnfants10.getText().length() == 0)) {...}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [compare string with equals method and ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524005/compare-string-with-equals-method-and)

Answer (score 0):

You could check it with

```
editTextName.getText().toString().equals("")
```

Comment: Yes but i have toi verify those are displayed

Answer (score 0):

You could check this with :

> [TextUtils.isEmpty](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence))(mEditText.getText().toString())

*Note: Why you don't use a list of EditText with an Adapter ?*

You will have an ArrayList which contain X EditText (according to your spinner number) and you create a "validate" methode which parse all arrayList and check if EditText is empty or not.

Comment: I don't see how to do your arraylist by the spinner, I know how to do in PHP, but I'm just beginning Android, can you show me an exemple ?

Comment: See this tutorial ( http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_example ) it's explain how to do an Adapter to link to a List. In  your  case you must add a custom constructor  for  first init and  another method  to update number (you update arraylist to get  expected number and  you call notifyDatasetChanged() it will update you list (ListView maybe) according to your  updated arraylist). And  finaly  add a method  validate  which parse  arraylist to check your  edittext.

Comment: I will see it, thank you, for my problem i found a solution, i check if edittext is visible then i see if its not empty :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as

```
if((mEditText.getText().toString()).equals("")){    

}else{    

}
```

Comment: Yes but i have toi verify those are displayed

Comment: keep all the objects of edittext to the list and  you can use loop to check if the edittext is visible or not and inside it check if it is empty or not